# Why does maintaining contraction of muscles require ATP?

Tags: human-biology

So from my understanding, if I maintain the contraction of my muscle, the myosin head will be bonded to the actin. Why is ATP needed to maintain this bond?

Answer (score 5):

Actually, it is not. ATP *releases* the myosin bonded to the actin, so when it is absent, the muscle remains contracted. This is, actually, precisely what happens during *rigor mortis* after death.

However, as long as you are alive, on a molecular level this is a dynamic process - actin release and bonding - and maintaining it requires energy. Moreover, muscle relaxation is not achieved by stopping the ATP flow, but incurrs additional ATP cost - it happens by actively removing calcium ions required to enable the actin to bind the myosin.